# No acceptable C compiler found in `$PATH`

Tags: gcc

Am trying to install `gcc`, but `configure` is telling me that

> there is no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH.

What can I do?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu and when trying to configure gcc, it is telling me that it requires a C compiler.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build `gcc` from source. Do you have any special reason for doing that, instead of just running `sudo apt install gcc`?

Comment: I do not know what version will be installed by `sudo apt install gcc`. And it all depends the version of ubuntu one uses.

Comment: @Vera with `apt-cache policy gcc` you wlll get the package version.

Comment: Can you interpret the result `vera@swv:~$ apt-cache policy gcc
gcc:
  Installed: 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
  Candidate: 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
  Version table:
 *** 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 500
        500 https://archive.trisquel.info/trisquel etiona-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://archive.trisquel.info/trisquel etiona-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 500
        500 https://archive.trisquel.info/trisquel etiona/main amd64 Packages
vera@smv:~$`

Comment: It is an old version of ubuntu and want to install the latest release than available from the repository.

Comment: You may be able to install a newer version of gcc semi-officially from the [toochain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=bionic)

Comment: @Vera, you can have as many gcc/g++ versions as you want, installed at the same time. The system version is a must : `sudo apt install g++` ........... gcc-11.x build example https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UxUOwTqZk9p9vbHffgIqxWWey6TU1HuMyCCTC9Htvj8/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is bootstrap build. It’s doable but hard.
The easiest solution is to install a compiler for your distribution and use that to build your version.
Once you have built your version, you can remove the distro compiler an use only your own one.

http://bootstrappable.org/

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Ubuntu, the easiest way to install `gcc` is with the package manager:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

But, if you want for some reason build it from source, you have to follow the steps detailed in [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html), check specially the [Prerequisites](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) section.

Comment: The problem has been that installing from source requires a C Compiler, which configure is complaining there in na C compiler installed.

Comment: @Vera does `sudo apt install g++` work?

Comment: Found out that I can resolve the problem by installing `build-essential`.